# Simple editor able to replace special caracters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working in a small text editor. Every content I typed on my id=content with any ^ should be replaced for nothing (^ for ''). Let's say I'm typed good ^night when I clicked on the ^ button at the top left of my editor should return just good night. I tried to organize it as best as possible to make my question clear. I'm just starting to code and I'm recently starting to browse and participate in forums. I added my stylesheet along with my code. Thanks for all the help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>AT - Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="toolbar">
        
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
             <button onclick = "escapeRegExp">^</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="content" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
        </div>
    </div>
         
</body>
</html>
```

My function

```
    <script>
    function escapeRegExp() {
        return content.replace(^, '');
    }
    </script>
```

My style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

li {
    margin-left: 16px;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
}




.container {
    max-width: 991px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.toolbar {
    padding: 16px;
    background: #eee;
}
.toolbar .head {
    display: flex;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.toolbar .head > input {
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    outline: none;
}
.toolbar .head select {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toolbar .head .color {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.toolbar .head .color span {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.toolbar .head .color input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toolbar .head .color input::-moz-color-swatch {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.toolbar .btn-toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.toolbar .btn-toolbar button {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.toolbar .btn-toolbar button:hover {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
#content {
    padding: 16px;
    outline: none;
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
#show-code[data-active="true"] {
    background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is only for "^" which would mean you could use

```
content.replaceAll('^', '');
```

Unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: If this is your code:

`    
<script>
    function escapeRegExp() {
        return content.replace(^, '');
    }
    </script>
`

then it is not the same as what I suggested